# Utilizar valor devuelto por metodo en otro metodo

Tags: java

me ha surgido la duda de al querer usar un valor que devuelve un metodo en otro metodo, y es que nose si la forma correcta seria pasando el primer metodo como parametro al segundo o igualando una variable al metodo primero dentro del segundo metodo.
Nose si me he explicado bien.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: En Java no se pueden pasar métodos como parámetros de otros métodos, como por ejemplo se puede hacer en Python. Una posible solución puede ser el uso del patrón "Template" https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patr%C3%B3n_de_m%C3%A9todo_de_la_plantilla

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. Nótese que esta pregunta tiene problemas de formato. Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tu pregunta es si es correcto esto:

```
new Metodo1(Metodo2());
```

¿cierto?, en donde **Metodo1** por ejemplo recibe un numero, y **Metodo2** retorna un numero.
Es completamente valido que hacerlo de manera separada:

```
int getM1=Metodo2();
new Metodo1(getM1);
```

Una diferencia podría ser que seria mas complicado interpretar la primera forma si se utilizan demasiados métodos.

Como conclusión, si es posible y valido pero eso depende del programador si es factible usarlo y claro, el **método pasado como parámetro** que va de parámetro obligatoria mente debe de devolver un **Valor u Objeto** correspondiente al parámetro del **primer método**.